# Where can I find the value of JUNIT_CONTAINER in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

I need to find out, in which path this following path is resolved:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
```

It's no classpath variabl to be found unter `Window->Preferences, Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables`.

Where can I found the value von `JUNIT_CONTAINER/4`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `classpathentry` of kind "con" means *classpath container*.

From [Java Class Paths help page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_classpath.htm):

> **entry denoting a classpath container**:
>   an indirect reference to a structured set of project or libraries.
>   Classpath containers are used to refer to a set of classpath entries that describe a complex library structure.
>   Like classpath variables, classpath containers ([IClasspathContainer](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IClasspathContainer.html)) are **dynamically resolved**.
>   Classpath containers may be used by different projects, causing their path entries to resolve to distinct values per project.
>   They also provide meta information about the library that they represent (name, kind, description of library.)

Classpath containers can be manipulated through JavaCore methods [getClasspathContainer](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.html#getClasspathContainer%28org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath%2C%20org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject%29) and setClasspathContainer.

---

So in your case, to be really sure about the resolved path, you could query your own project through those calls, like this [`ClassPathUtils`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid0A2F5DFD970E39A042E83CBD14A2E0773A43564D.aspx?s=getclasspathcontainer#L83)

```
case IClasspathEntry.CPE_CONTAINER:
{
   final IClasspathContainer container;

   try
   {
      container = JavaCore.getClasspathContainer( entry.getPath(), jproj );
   }
   catch( JavaModelException e )
   {
      Logger.getLogger().logError( e );
      continue;
   }

   if( container != null ) 
   {
      final IClasspathEntry[] containerEntries
        = container.getClasspathEntries();

      for( int j = 0; j < containerEntries.length; j++ )
      {
        resolved.add( containerEntries[ j ].getPath() );
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Help -> About Eclipse Platform -> Configuration Details.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is this little JUnit test.
It must be a test, because Eclipse only sets the needed libraries to the classpath System Property:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestApp {
    @Test
    public void bla() {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```